# Prefilter in searchmodel from index controller

Tags: mysql, yii2

I have a search model name MedicalInformationSearch which is having a property as `user_id`.
I have also defined a relation - `joinwith(['user','profile'])`. The profile table is also having a property as `user_id`

In the MedicalInformationController - in Index action to prefilter medical information by patient for logged in user I have added

```
$searchModel->user_id = Yii::$app->user->identity->id;
```

but now I am getting error like

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'user_id' in where clause is ambiguous
The SQL being executed was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `medical_information` LEFT JOIN `user` ON `medical_information`.`user_id` = `user`.`id` LEFT JOIN `user_profile` ON `medical_information`.`user_id` = `user_profile`.`user_id` WHERE `user_id`=3
```

the error being both table `user_profile` and `medical_information` is having user_id column.
so how I can modify this to specify that user_id to be used from `medical_information` and not from user_profile.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I am still looking for how to specify the specific model or table in the above syntax. but I am able to achieve the result in another way.

here is the detail of action.

```
public function actionIndex()
    {
        
        $searchModel = new MedicalInformationSearch();
        $user_id = Yii::$app->user->identity->id;
        $cond = "medical_information.user_id = $user_id";       
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams,$cond);

        return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first code is correct, just set in your `search` function table name.

```
 $query->andFilterWhere([
     'medical_information.user_id' => $this->user_id,
 ]);
```

Or in second way send user_id like function parameter:

```
 $user_id = Yii::$app->user->identity->id;    
 $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams, $user_id);
```

and your query in search function

```
$query = MedicalInformation::find()->where(['medical_information.user_id' => $user_id]);
....
```